# Program generates 50 random numbers (between 1 to 10) and tells the amount of values that are smaller than 5 and bigger than 5 (C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement, random, visual-studio-2015, numbers

**Program generates 50 random numbers (between 1 to 10) and tells the amount of values that are smaller than 5 and bigger than 5 (C#)**

Comment: Interesting. Can we go further?

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment

Comment: Yes. I'm a beginner of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
Random r = new Random();
int n = 50;
int smaller_than_5 = 0;
int bigger_than_5 = 0;
double[] d = new double[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    d[i] = 1 + r.NextDouble() * 9;
    if (d[i] < 5) smaller_than_5++;
    else if (d[i] > 5) bigger_than_5++;
}
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: so you use array algorithms, I haven't learned it yet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int n = 50
IList<int> randomNumbers = new List<int>(n);
Random ran = new Random(1);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     randomNumbers.Add(ran.Next(1, 10));
}

int lessThan5Count = randomNumbers.Count(c => c < 5);
int greaterThan5Count = randomNumbers.Count(c => c > 5);
```